# SharePoint tasks fields dependencies

Tags: sharepoint, parent-child

I have a list of tasks and one of its fields is reference to another task in the list, and another field is boolean value.

the boolean value of the tasks is false. I want the booleans to be dependent on the related task's boolean value.

One can't be true unless the other one is changed to true.
Sort of Parent-Child Relationship.

Any idea how it can be done?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I would go for ItemUpdating event receiver and show an error message when trying to save the item. Of course, it is not the most user-friendly solution.
The other way is to develop a custom Yes/No field and include the logic in its code, a bit more tricky, but much nicer